# Comparable type in extension module

Tags: python, cpython

To implement != and == for my CPython extension type, should I implement `tp_compare`, `tp_richcompare` or both?

Under what circumstances is each of them called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tp_richcompare` is analogous to the rich comparison [special methods](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) in the Python language itself. It is chosen in preference to `tp_compare` when the comparison operators are invoked on the class.

Use `tp_richcompare` when you want finer control over the comparison logic. For instance, there might be a very cheap way to determine equality, but not precedence. Say `memcmp(a, b, sizeof(*a)) == 0` indicates that two very complex data structures are equal, but `memcmp(a, b, sizeof(*a)) < 0` doesn't indicate that `a` is less than `b`, which instead requires an expensive algorithm to determine. The `tp_compare` function would require that you always use the expensive algorithm in order to return either a `-1`, `0` or `1`. The `tp_richcompare` function, OTOH, tells you which comparison is intended, so you can choose either the expensive or the cheap algorithm, depending on the need at hand.

An additional advantage of `tp_richcompare` is that you can raise exceptions for operations that don't make sense, such as `u < v` where `u` and `v` are points in space.

Comment: Thanks, that's made it very clear. Am I right in thinking that, if I decide to implement `tp_richcompare`, I should also implement `tp_compare` to support the built-in `cmp` function?

Comment: @James: Good question; I honestly don't know. I will hazard a guess that `cmp` doesn't make use of the rich comparison functions because it would be too awkward, especially since no relationship between the rich comparisons is assumed (`<` need not be the opposite of `>=`).

Comment: @James:  No, you don't need `tp_compare` at all if you've got `tp_richcompare`.  Witness the many built-in Python types (e.g., `float`) that implement `tp_richcompare` but not `tp_compare`, and yet still work with `cmp`.

Comment: And to add to this answer, `tp_compare` is gone in Python 3.x, so `tp_richcompare` is more future-proof, if you care about that.

Comment: @James, @Mark: Yes indeed, tp_compare is unnecessary. `cmp` calls `__eq__`, `__lt__` and `__gt__` in turn. Ironically, it returns `1` even if they all return False, which makes me wonder why it bothers to call `__gt__`.

Comment: @Marcelo:  I believe that if all of `__lt__`, `__eq__` and `__gt__` return False then the comparison is treated as not implemented, and Python falls back to its default comparison rules involving comparing object id's.  So the `__gt__` result isn't ignored, exactly:  if it had returned `True` then that would have been used as the basis of the comparison result.

Comment: Hmm. I just tried `cmp(a, b)` and `cmp(b, a)` for two objects that return False for all their rich comparisons. Both calls returned `1`. Now I'm all confused again!